# Istio: balance traffic across namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I'm trying to set up balancing between applications in different namespaces with Istio. But I am always getting reply from one application in dev namespace. My point is get response from applications from same prefix, like: http://example.com - need to balance between namespaces `dev`, `staging`, `production`

I deployed `VirtualService`, `DestinationRule` and `Gateway` in different namespaces. Also I have tried to deploy one `Gateway` in the `istio-system` namespace and set correct path to it in the all of `VirtualService`.
Obviously I don't understand how it works...
My `VirtualService`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-vs
  namespace: dev
spec:
  hosts:
  - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - dev/istio-nginx-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.dev.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-vs
  namespace: staging
spec:
  hosts:
  - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - staging/istio-nginx-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.staging.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-vs
  namespace: production
spec:
  hosts:
  - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - production/istio-nginx-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.production.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

Here is the `DestinationRule`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: dev
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.svc.dev.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: staging
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.staging.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: production
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.production.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
```

And the `Gateway`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-gw
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: istio-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-gw
  namespace: staging
spec:
  selector:
    app: istio-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-gw
  namespace: production
spec:
  selector:
    app: istio-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - xxx.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 2):

As the hosts "xxx.elb.amazonaws.com" value in different gateway definitions of different namespace is same for the "istio-nginx" service.  So only one routing rule would have got applied.  So the requests would be serviced from single application.  For more details on routing rule precedence can be referred in [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#routing-rule-precedence)

Using 'istioctl" tool you can verify the routes configured.

```
istioctl pc routes deploy/istio-ingressgateway.istio-system | grep "istio-nginx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Might be useful to someone. I have create one gateway and one VirtualService in istio-system namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-gw
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: istio-gateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - xxx.elb.amazonaws.com
  gateways:
  - istio-system/istio-nginx-gw
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.dev.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v1
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 33
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.staging.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v2
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 33
    - destination:
        host: istio-nginx.production.svc.cluster.local
        subset: v3
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 33
```

And add three Destination rules

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: dev
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.dev.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - name: v1
      labels:
        app: istio-nginx
        version: v1
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: staging
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.staging.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - name: v2
      labels:
        app: istio-nginx
        version: v2
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: istio-nginx-dr
  namespace: production
spec:
  host: istio-nginx.production.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
    - name: v3
      labels:
        app: istio-nginx
        version: v3
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
```

My application in dev/staging/production namespaces has the `version` labels: v1/v2/v3
[image]